# C# getting "The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar." error

Tags: c#

When parsing string "99991231535959" using `DateTime.ParseExact`, I'm getting

> "The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar." error.

Code:

```
var convertedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss",
             System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

Comment: "99991231535959" is max datetime value

Comment: Can you show the code? I'd say you have your format wrong or something like that... Also it's not really clear why you'd want to parse the max value like this.

Comment: Here's the code:
`var convertedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat);`

I'm getting this value from database and I need to display in long date string format.

Comment: there are only 23 hours in a day, not 53: 99991231**53**5959. Your database contains incorrect data

Comment: Honestly, I figured that but then I thought maybe my format string is incorrect. However, the same code works for all other cases so far.  So, is the code alright?

Comment: Side note: http://xkcd.com/1179/ is more standard and easier to read...

Comment: Any more directions/suggestions on this?